# How do I protect chart code?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying to keep a chart from being changed once it is written. I've gathered code from the web that should do this:

```
Sub test()
Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
Dim MyChart As Chart

Set myChartObject = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=400, Height:=300)

Set MyChart = myChartObject.Chart

MyChart.PlotArea.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(2.583)
MyChart.PlotArea.Height = Application.InchesToPoints(1.75)

MyChart.ChartType = xlLine

MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A5:D9")
MyChart.Protect Password:="pass", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True

End Sub
```

I get an error on the `MyChart.Protect` line. I am not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can protect a chart unless it is also a worksheet. Since you are inserting  the chart into a worksheet, either protect the worksheet replace

```
MyChart.Protect Password:="pass", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="pass", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True
```

or insert the chart as a worksheet